# 'Enable system diagnostics' missing in release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As given in the pic below, how can we enable 'Enable system diagnostics' in release pipeline? The pic is taken from build pipeline and the documentation for diagnostics is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops). Also is it possible to provide this in Yaml ?

[image]

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the variable `system.debug` to `true`. If the variable does not exist, add it.

Comment: Added that but still Enable system diagnostics is not showing when we create release

Comment: @BlueClouds That variable controls whether it shows diagnostic output. Setting `system.debug` to `true` is effectively the same as having that checkbox clicked.

Comment: I have added a question here to confirm the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60258663/azure-devops-pipeline-difference-between-system-debug-and-enable-system-diagn