# Azure Devops Pipeline : Difference between system.debug and 'Enable system diagnostics'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

If we use the UI of build pipeline, we see 'enable system diagnostics' check box as given below. There is also a default variable 'system.debug'.

What is the difference between these two?

One comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152692/enable-system-diagnostics-missing-in-release-pipeline?noredirect=1#comment106580827_60152692) states both could be the same. But if we set system.debug is set to 'true' 'enable system diagnostics' is still unchecked.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They both are the same. It is given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops#configure-verbose-logs). The main purpose is to set the variable for automated runs. But it can be used for single runs too, which makes the UI checkbox, the additional duplicate feature, pointless.

It is confusing because it appears in build pipeline and not in release pipeline. Also when we run , like you said, even when the variable is set to true, the UI is still not updated(unchecked). Which might require double work(checking diagnostics too) like I did for some time.

"To configure verbose logs for all runs, you can add a variable named system.debug and set its value to true." And ignore the UI check box